# How to retrieve the arraylist of object between two activities

Tags: android, android-activity

Assume that I when I am have a unique arrayList in activity A. Whenever, I go to activity B, I  add a note to indicate that my arrayList in A contains some object; and whenever I click on the note in activity B, I will go back to Activity A and get back my unique arrayList data.
I am stuck on the last step, because whenever I go back to activity A from B, I just create a new Intent. Any hint plz?

Comment: You want to send back data to the activity that started Activity B?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass object or list of object from ActivityA to ActivityB then you can pass using `Serialization` or `Parcelable`.

Comment: Is there another way without using Serialization or Parcelable. I have tried that and it worked well. But I intend to have a difference approach that involving the activity lifecycle. For example, intent = old Intent( this, Acitivity.class ) ~.~

Answer (score 0):

Using Activities the best way is passing `Serializable` or `Parcelable` objects in the `Activity` `Bundle`, here, your `Objects` will have to implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable` interface.

Another more modern approach in Android would be the usage of `Fragments`. On this way you will have an `Activity` and `Fragment`. Your `Activity` holds the data and the `Fragment` shows the notes you want, to pass the data you implement an interface where you can easily pass the data between the `Activity` and the `Fragment` without using `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.

- Detailed explanation about `Fragments` [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)
- Detailed explanation about `Fragment` communication [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html%20%22%22)